# catkin_make error while building hector_slam

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, python3, boost

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i was working on mavros in jetson nano(melodic, aarch64)
i have cloned this to my catkin_ws:

```
git clone https://github.com/Slamtec/rplidar_ros.git
git clone https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam.git
```

but when I catkin_make I get this Boost library error:

```
Base path: /home/slam/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/slam/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/slam/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/slam/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/slam/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/slam/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/slam/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/slam/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/slam/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/slam/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/melodic


 -- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/melodic

-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found suitable version "2.7.17", minimum required is "2") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python2
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/slam/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gtests will be built

-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gmock will be built
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found version "2.7.17") 
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.29
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

-- ~~  traversing 19 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - hector_geotiff_launch
-- ~~  - hector_slam (metapackage)
-- ~~  - hector_slam_launch
-- ~~  - opencv_tests
-- ~~  - hector_map_tools
-- ~~  - hector_nav_msgs
-- ~~  - vision_opencv (metapackage)
-- ~~  - hector_geotiff

-- ~~  - hector_geotiff_plugins
-- ~~  - hector_marker_drawing
-- ~~  - cv_bridge
-- ~~  - image_geometry
-- ~~  - hector_compressed_map_transport
-- ~~  - rplidar_ros
-- ~~  - hector_imu_attitude_to_tf
-- ~~  - hector_imu_tools
-- ~~  - hector_map_server

-- ~~  - hector_trajectory_server
-- ~~  - hector_mapping
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_geotiff_launch'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_geotiff_launch)
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'hector_slam'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_slam)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 

'hector_slam_launch'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_slam_launch)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'opencv_tests'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(vision_opencv/opencv_tests)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_map_tools'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_map_tools)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_nav_msgs'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_nav_msgs)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- hector_nav_msgs: 0 messages, 5 services

-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'vision_opencv'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(vision_opencv/vision_opencv)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_geotiff'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_geotiff)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_geotiff_plugins'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_geotiff_plugins)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_marker_drawing'

-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_marker_drawing)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'cv_bridge'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(vision_opencv/cv_bridge)
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (found version "2.7.17") 
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/Fin

dBoost.cmake:1626 (message):
  No header defined for python37; skipping header check
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  vision_opencv/cv_bridge/CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1947 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.



 Boost version: 1.65.1

  Boost include path: /usr/include

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_python37

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  vision_opencv/cv_bridge/CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)

-- Found OpenCV: /usr (found suitable version "4.1.1", minimum required is "4") found components:  opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_imgcodecs 
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (found suitable version "2.7.17", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'image_geometry'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(vision_opencv/image_geometry)
-- Found OpenCV: /usr (found version "4.1.1") 
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_compressed_map_transport'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_compressed_map_transport)

-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rplidar_ros'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(rplidar_ros)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_imu_attitude_to_tf'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_imu_attitude_to_tf)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_imu_tools'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_imu_tools)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_map_server'


-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_map_server)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_trajectory_server'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_trajectory_server)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_mapping'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_slam/hector_mapping)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:

--   thread
--   chrono
--   system
--   date_time
--   atomic
-- hector_mapping: 2 messages, 0 services
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "/home/slam/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/slam/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

though I do not have python3.7 installed in my system. it is pointing to  `boost_python37`
what am I doing wrong here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370549/catkin_make-error-while-building-hector_slam/) by [siddharthcb](https://answers.ros.org/users/63487/siddharthcb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2021-01-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-01-29**:
Did you install the requisite dependencies using `rosdep` ?

**Comment by [siddharthcb](https://answers.ros.org/users/63487/siddharthcb/) on 2021-01-29**:
i did follow these steps after installing ros.

```
sudo apt install python-rosdep
sudo rosdep init
rosdep update
```

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-01-29**:
From your catkin workspace folder (i.e. inside `~/catkin_ws`), you need to run this -

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y
```

See this [link](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep).

**Comment by [siddharthcb](https://answers.ros.org/users/63487/siddharthcb/) on 2021-01-29**:
still no luck. i am getting the same error :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

so the default in [hector-slam](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam) is set to ros-noetic when you clone. I had to clone melodic-devel package for my system and the problem is SOLVED.

---

Originally posted by [siddharthcb](https://answers.ros.org/users/63487/siddharthcb/) with karma: 100 on 2021-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-02-02**:
Oh okay. I didn't think of that.
Glad you could resolve the issue :-)